# What determines which pokemon you are allowed to place at a gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

So I defeated a Team Valor gym earlier today using my highest cp Pidgeot. It turned grey, so I went to claim it with that Pidgeot, except it wouldn't let me. What determines which pokemon you are allowed to place at a gym? Is it just those who have participated in a battle can't? Is there a time period for it? What about training at a friendly gym? Does this impact anything?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm pretty sure a Pokemon needs to be at full HP to be placed in a gym, so the reason yours wasn't available was because it was hurt from the previous battle. Heal it to full with potions and it will be available.

Comment: Yes this is correct, my friend also tried placing the pokemon which he fought with and couldn't until he healed it. Not sure if it needs to be at full hp or nearly full hp though.

Comment: Probably full, mine was at nearly full

Comment: Literally has to be full hp. I tested this with a 52 hp starmie.

Comment: In popular areas, you may not have time to heal your pokemon before the gym is sniped by an opposing team. Always try to keep a strong spare healed up to place immediately in the gym if you really want it.

Answer (score 9):

Your pokemon needs to be:

-Full hp
-Not actively in another gym

Tips:

-Keep your best pokemon of each type with you, put the 2nd best ones inside gyms.
-Try to put pokemon that are not weak to the pokemon types in that area. For example, do not put water pokemon in gyms where there is a lot of electric pokemon spawns. Or you'll lose that gym immediately.