# Pokémon Go won't allow training at friendly gyms

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm trying to add my best Pokemon but my higher-level ones aren't showing as available. There are already friendly there with the same CP level as the one I'm trying to add but they will only allow me to add much lower CP Pokemon.

Comment: Have you checked to see if they need to be revived?

Comment: [Related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273400/what-determines-which-pokemon-you-are-allowed-to-place-at-a-gym?rq=1)?

Answer (score 3):

You can place a Pokémon into a gym if

- it is fully healed (and obviously is not fainted),
- it is not your Buddy
- it is not already in another gym

Thus, if your Pokémon is not showing in the list where you pick which one to place into a gym, it is because it violates one of the conditions above.